# Do you know any open-source asp.net web control to render code?

Tags: controls, asp.net-2.0

I'm looking for an asp.net control capable of formatting code written in certain programming languages (as in StackOverflow or the "Language" functionality in Notepad++), with automatic syntax highlighting/indentation depending on the language.

Do you know of any such control?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know any asp.net control that does that, but you could use a JavaScript syntax highlighter, like this one : http://code.google.com/p/syntaxhighlighter/.

The main advantage is that it moves the rendering cost to the client side, which can be a huge gain for a highly-frequented website with a lot of code (eg programming forum/website like SO.. wait... they do that too, right ?).